# Creating alternating 0 and 1 values based on changing data value

Tags: sql

I have data in my sql database and need to create changeControl value.

```
data   changeControl
M-0101  0
M-0101  0
M-02    1
M-03    0
OT-014  1
OT-014  1
M-228   0
M-228   0
```

Are there any way to create this changeControl value depend on data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an easy way, but it depend on your DB.

In SQL Server and in Oracle you can use DENSE_RANK() to get the order of the values, using that you'll have the same number for equal values

In SQL Server

```
SELECT data
     , (DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY data) - 1) % 2 changeControl
FROM   Table1
```

In Oracle the `%` is not present, we need to use the function `MOD()`

```
SELECT data
     , MOD((DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY data) - 1), 2) changeControl
FROM   Table1
```

In MySQL there is no `DENSE_RANK`, but there is another way to get the result

```
SELECT data, changeControl
FROM   (SELECT @last
             , data
             , @id := CASE WHEN @last <> data THEN 1 - @id 
                           WHEN @last = data THEN @id 
                           ELSE 0 
                      END changeControl
             , @last:= data
        FROM   Table1
             , (SELECT @id := 0) a) b
```

if you don't mind additional column you can run directly the subquery.

p.s.: If you don't specify what DB you're using we have to guess.

Comment: Agreed, this is a much better solution, didn't know about DENSE_RANK.

Comment: Thank you soo much for answer. Sorry for missing tag, it was MS-SQL

Answer (score 1):

You need to first break your data into groups, and assign each group a number. 
Then join this information with main table, sort by data, and take modulo by two from group number - this will be your changeControl column.

```
select tn.*, t.RN % 2 as changeControl from tableName tn
left join 
(select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY data) AS RN, data
from tableName group by data) t
on t.data = tn.data
order by tn.data
```

This problem cannot be solved by taking modulo by two of id or data hash - id keeps changing even for identical values, and two sequential hashes although may be different, can both be even, producing same 'changeControl' value.

Comment: Thank you result is as I want, just as you said there is no simple way to do it.

Comment: I don't think this is the correct answer, i tried it and the output is different (0/1) then in the Question. And by default, rows without a 'rowversion' are not ordered.

Comment: Yes, the values are inverted, not like in op's question. But it is easy to fix that, just replace t.RN % 2 with 1 - (t.RN % 2). sqlfiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d9a93/2

Answer (score 0):

You can create alternatining 0 and 1 values for change control column based on where id is odd or even

```
SELECT id , data ,
       CASE WHEN id%2=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as changecontrol
FROM tableName
```

**EDIT**

```
SELECT id , data ,
      CASE WHEN 
               RIGHT(data,LEN(data) - CHARINDEX('-',data)) % 2 = 0 
           THEN 1 
           ELSE 0 END as changecontrol
FROM tableName
```

Comment: but it should create "columnData" depent on data value not id

Comment: change i%2==0 to i%2=0 , sql server uses single `=` for comparison

Comment: how many digits after M- are possible , is it only double digits ?

Comment: for example M-10085, OT-12452... also possible. so you mean I can get integer part from data and use your solution?

Answer (score 0):

To implement this, you should handle the [RowStyle](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_RowStyletopic) event of the GridView.  Here is some sample code:

```
using DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid;

private void gridView1_RowStyle(object sender, 
DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.RowStyleEventArgs e) {
   GridView View = sender as GridView;
   if(e.RowHandle >= 0) {
      int changeControl = Convert.ToInt32(View.GetRowCellValue(e.RowHandle, View.Columns["changeControl"]));
      if(changeControl == 1) {
         e.Appearance.BackColor = Color.Salmon;
      }            
      else
         e.Appearance.BackColor = Color.SeaShell;
   }
}
```

Please also review this example:

[How to change a row style based on a column value](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/A264)

Comment: but I dont know how to create "changeControl" data

Comment: do you need to create additional column in the XtraGrid which will contain this calculated values?  use unbound column for this.  Here is a link explaining how they can be used:https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument1477

Comment: thank you for your comment but the problem I dont know how to create changeControl data in sql. its not about grid.

Comment: I wonder, who has downvoted my answer and why?  The original question has had the "devexpress" and "xtragrid" tag

Comment: I did. The question is about SQL, yet you assume usage of 3rd party tools  and from what i see C# (not sure what other languages are supported TBH), but the fact is, the question was for SQL. And sorry, i didnt see the original question, i am going by the only tag i see, SQL.

Comment: I am soo sorry, I had put devex tag but then I saw your answer and understand it causes misunderstanding. Then I removed that tag